# Problems with virtual host

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'm using Xampp, and I'm developing a web app.

in httpd-vhosts.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/ProgettoTimelinegit/api"
    ServerName timeline.dev
     <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/ProgettoTimelinegit/web/app/index.html">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
         AllowOverride Authconfig FileInfo
         Require all granted
        </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

and in etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 timeline.dev
```

On my browser I write timeline.dev it reaches the html but it's not rendered well because the path are not ok.
**My intention would be that when I write timeline.dev it goes right to** `htdocs/ProgettoTimelinegit/web/app/index.html` .

in /api/index.php (that calls the routes) there is the backend and in /web the frontend .
Why if I write 'timeline.dev/index.php/route' in the http request,it appends like this ?

```
localhost:9000/timeline.dev/index.php/route
```

Comment: `DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/ProgettoTimelinegit/web/app` and ditch the `<Directory>` ?

Comment: What does javascript have to do with this? Please do not just add tags just because they are suggested, make sure they have something to do with your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change 
`DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/ProgettoTimelinegit/api"` to 
`DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/ProgettoTimelinegit/app"`